# Different behaviour of MPI 2.1 and MPI 3.0 implementaion. (MPI + OpenMP)

Tags: mpi, openmp, openmpi

Is it necessary to set OMP_NUM_THREADS variable when you run MPI program which includes openmp code? When I see some tutorials, I saw that you MUST set OMP_NUM_THREADS (environmental variable). Im testing programs on my home cluster which is using OpenMPI 1.6.4 (MPI 2.1) to pass messages. My MPI program includes openMP function call (omp_get_max_threads) and I dont set OMP_NUM_THREADS variable before I run MPI program. The program works correctly and returns the real number of threads. If I try to launch this program on another cluster which use newer version of MPI implementation (MPI 3.0), program returns me 1 as a result of omp_get_max_threads() call.I used **-fopenmp** option when my program was compiling. I used mpicc to compile my program.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int rank=-1;
int n=-1;
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
n=omp_get_max_threads();
printf("Hello from %d, omp_get_max_threads returned me %d\n",rank,omp_get_max_threads());
MPI_Finalize(); 
return 0;}
```

What is wrong? How to sovle? If you dont belive me here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwmQz.png) of debug window(program output+values(upper right corner))

I have tried some MPI options(-H) and run this program on 1 HOST. Im using OpenMPI 1.8.1.Check out program output:

```
[hpc@server Debug]$ mpirun -np 1 -H  localhost  ./mpiTest
Hello from 0, omp_get_max_threads returned me 2
[hpc@server Debug]$ mpirun -np 2 -H  localhost  ./mpiTest
Hello from 0, omp_get_max_threads returned me 8
Hello from 1, omp_get_max_threads returned me 8
[hpc@server Debug]$ mpirun -np 2 -hostfile ./hostfile  ./mpiTest
Hello from 0, omp_get_max_threads returned me 2
Hello from 1, omp_get_max_threads returned me 2
[hpc@server Debug]$ mpirun -H server,server -np 2 ./mpiTest 
Hello from 0, omp_get_max_threads returned me 2
Hello from 1, omp_get_max_threads returned me 2
[hpc@server Debug]$ mpirun -H server -np 2 ./mpiTest 
Hello from 0, omp_get_max_threads returned me 8
Hello from 1, omp_get_max_threads returned me 8
```

The second time it returned me correct number of cpu threads. How can it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default most OpenMP implementations set the maximum number of threads equal to the number of logical CPUs. This default doesn't work very well in combination with MPI. For example, if you launch 2 hybrid MPI+OpenMP processes on the same node, each one of them would try to use all available CPUs and this will result in oversubscription. That's why on our cluster we set `OMP_NUM_THREADS` to 1 for all MPI jobs and if the user is launching hybrid ones, (s)he must explicitly set `OMP_NUM_THREADS` to the desired number of threads per MPI process.

The proper way to start hybrid jobs with Open MPI depends on your cluster environment. You should set `OMP_NUM_THREADS` to some sane value and then either have the resource manager propagate the value to all MPI processes or do that explicitly.

If Open MPI is compiled with tight integration with the cluster resource manager (SGE, LSF, PBS, Torque, etc.), the following (as part of the job script) would suffice:

```sh
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
mpiexec -n 4 ./program <program arguments>
```

This will launch 4 MPI processes with 4 OpenMP threads each.

Otherwise the `-x` option has to be used in order to pass the value of `OMP_NUM_THREADS` to the MPI processes:

```
$ export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
$ mpiexec -x OMP_NUM_THREADS -H host1,host2,host3,host4 -n 4 ./program
```

---

Open MPI 1.8.x introduced process binding by default. You can verify it by adding the `--report-bindings` option to `mpiexec` and observe the printed binding information. By default MPI processes are bound to a single (and different) CPU core each. That's why the OpenMP runtime only uses a single thread by default on machines with single hardware thread per core - launching more than one thread on a single core won't benefit most programs.

To restore the behaviour back to the one of Open MPI 1.6.x, add the `--bind-to none` command line option which disables the binding:

```
$ mpiexec --report-bindings -np 2 ./test
[cluster:28358] MCW rank 1 bound to socket 0[core 1[hwt 0]]: [./B/./././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.]
[cluster:28358] MCW rank 0 bound to socket 0[core 0[hwt 0]]: [B/././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.]
Hello from 0, omp_get_max_threads returned me 1
Hello from 1, omp_get_max_threads returned me 1

$ mpiexec --bind-to none --report-bindings -np 2 ./test
[cluster:28743] MCW rank 1 is not bound (or bound to all available processors)
[cluster:28743] MCW rank 0 is not bound (or bound to all available processors)
Hello from 0, omp_get_max_threads returned me 64
Hello from 1, omp_get_max_threads returned me 64
```

When you specify the `-H` option, each host listed there provides **a single slot**. When you ask Open MPI to launch more processes than the slots specified (i.e. you oversubscribe the hosts), the library switches off the default binding. That's why the combination `-H localhost -np 1` results in two threads being used, since you provide one slot and ask for one process, therefore that process is bound to a single core (in your case the cores appear to have two hardware threads). The combination `-H localhost -np 2` asks for two processes on a single slot, i.e. oversubscription, therefore the library disables the binding mechanism and the two MPI processes have access to all 8 hardware threads. The combination `-H server,server -np 2` provides two slots for two processes, i.e. no oversubscription, therefore the binding is active.

```
$ mpiexec -H localhost --report-bindings -np 1 ./test
[cluster:21425] MCW rank 0 bound to socket 0[core 0[hwt 0]]: [B/././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.]
Hello from 0, omp_get_max_threads returned me 1

$ mpiexec -H localhost --report-bindings -np 2 ./test
[cluster:38895] MCW rank 1 is not bound (or bound to all available processors)
[cluster:38895] MCW rank 0 is not bound (or bound to all available processors)
Hello from 1, omp_get_max_threads returned me 64
Hello from 0, omp_get_max_threads returned me 64

$ mpiexec -H localhost,localhost --report-bindings -np 2 ./test
[cluster:39329] MCW rank 1 bound to socket 0[core 1[hwt 0]]: [./B/./././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.]
[cluster:39329] MCW rank 0 bound to socket 0[core 0[hwt 0]]: [B/././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.][./././././././.]
Hello from 1, omp_get_max_threads returned me 1
Hello from 0, omp_get_max_threads returned me 1
```

Comment: I have added some strings to my  question's body\

Comment: @maxi, see the updated answer. I would recommend that you read the documentation of [mpiexec](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man1/mpiexec.1.php) from the 1.8.x series and make yourself familiar with the binding mechanism.

Comment: is there any analogues for this options in mpich library?

Comment: Yes, the Hydra process manager supports binding - see [here](https://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Using_the_Hydra_Process_Manager#Process-core_Binding).